# Find bases of the kernel and image of the orthogonal projection onto the x -axis in {R}^3.

Tags: linear-transformations

I'm not given a function of any kinda just asked to find 2 3x1 kernal and a 3x1 image. I'm not sure how I'd even go about doing this.

Comment: You are in fact given a function: the orthogonal projection of vectors onto the $x$-axis. Do you know what an orthogonal projection is? (not being snarky—we need context to be able to help you)

Comment: No I do not. Professor never covered it. I'm also not a theorem/defination learner which is why this class kicked my ass last semester at this point and I failed. I need to see worked out things to learn math.

Comment: Ok, let's zero in on where you are. One way of defining the function that orthogonally projects onto the $x$-axis in $\Bbb R^3$ is by saying that it maps $(a,b,c)$ to $(a,0,0)$. GIven this formula for the function, are you able to solve the problem?